# Get assets directory from an android function name or variable instead of hard-coded

Tags: java, android, directory, android-assets

Read many questions about the location of assets. Not any of these solutions uses a function to get the assets foldername/dirname/pathname, only hard-coded like: `"file:///android_asset/"`.

For example to get a path you can do something like this:

```
String sFilesPath = mContext.getFilesDir().getPath();
```

Is there a function or variable in Android to get the full path to the assets folder?

Comment: No not only hard coded like that. Moreover your app cannot even use that. It's something specific used by a WebView. Your app can only use getAssetsManager().open() to open files.

Comment: And to get the database path you better use getDatabasePath().

Comment: @greenapps: Both of your comments are unnecessary. The subject Is not the case you talk about.

Comment: Of course pointing out your misconceptions is necessary. You would not keep on living with them do you?.There is no full path to the assets 'folder' as it is no folder on the file system. You cannot use File class and others for files in assets. You can only open an input stream as already described in comment.

Comment: Changed it, satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to get Absolute path for your `assets` folder as they come with your `apk`. If you need to access the `assets` folder you need to use `file:///android_asset` only. There is no other way.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer. Hmm, in some way kinda strange. What if this will change in the future. I know, this can be linked/mapped to another location, but it's weird. It's like with windows, when installed with a different configuration, hard coded strings can cause programs to fail. Is this an error by design or is there a reason to do it this way?

Comment: No. Your app cannot use that. Only for a WebView.

Comment: I'm using a webview, just wonder why there is no function or variable. When you must open a file inside the apk you need to specify this path.